# How to map number to color using matplotlib's colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider a variable `x` containing a floating point number. I want to use matplotlib's colormaps to map this number to a color, but not plot anything. Basically, I want to be able to choose the colormap with `mpl.cm.autumn` for example, use `mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin = -20, vmax = 10)` to set the range, and then map `x` to the corresponding color. But I really don't get the documentation of `mpl.cm`, so if anyone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

It's as simple as `cm.hot(0.3)`:

```py
import matplotlib.cm as cm
    
print(cm.hot(0.3))
```

```
(0.8240081481370484, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

If you also want to have the normalizer, use

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
   
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-20, vmax=10)
cmap = cm.hot
x = 0.3

m = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
print(m.to_rgba(x))
```

```
(1.0, 0.8225486412996345, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: how do you omit the alpha value in cm.hot()?

Answer (score 25):

You can get a color from a colormap by supplying an argument between 0 and 1, e.g. `cm.autumn(0.5)`.

If there is a normalization instance in the game, use the return of the Normalization instead:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

cmap = cm.autumn
norm = Normalize(vmin=-20, vmax=10)
print cmap(norm(5))
```

Comment: This way of using the API certainly looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Number value to colormap color

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib as matplotlib

def color_map_color(value, cmap_name='Wistia', vmin=0, vmax=1):
    # norm = plt.Normalize(vmin, vmax)
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
    cmap = cm.get_cmap(cmap_name)  # PiYG
    rgb = cmap(norm(abs(value)))[:3]  # will return rgba, we take only first 3 so we get rgb
    color = matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex(rgb)
    return color
```