# Python .txt file with numbers to rgba

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, 3d

Can someone help me with my project?
I would like to save the data from a few temperature sensors via a data logger into a file and then analyze this with a Python program.
That's my problem.
After processing the data, then create an interactive 3D map that uses the measurements of the sensors as color gradation.

I'm sorry in advance, in case I missed something, or did not provide enough information. This is my first question that I ask here. I have not worked with Python before, so I'm still a "noob".

Enclosed I have the current code.
I hope it's obvious what I want but the error I get when I want to use the data in the .txt file for RGB / RGBA is:

10., 20., 30., 40., 50., 60., 50., 60., 50., 40., 30., 20., 10. -> Invalid RGBA argument: nan or, if I have it convert to an array Invalid RGBA argument: 0.0

I found out that the RGB values ​​can only be processed between 0.0 and 1.0, but my "color" array was ok (see code)

I do not see the mistake. I hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

/ Minimal: (where the error could be)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D, get_test_data
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

data_file = np.genfromtxt('data_file.txt', delimiter=',')
color = mpl.colors.to_rgba_array(data_file[:,0], alpha=None)

c = np.abs(color)
cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color, s=50, c=c, cmap=cmhot)
```

/ Complete code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D, get_test_data
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame 


# set up a figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

########################the part not working#########################

# load the data file
data_file = np.genfromtxt('data_file.txt', delimiter=',')

#possible processing / not working
#data_file = np.array(data_file)
#data_file = (data_file-min(data_file))/(max(data_file)-min(data_file))

# parse good sensor data from imported data
color = mpl.colors.to_rgba_array(data_file[:,0], alpha=None)

########################the part not working#########################

arrA = ([[ -4. ],
         [ 0. ],
         #...etc.
         [ 0. ],
         [ 4. ]])

arrB = ([[ -4. ],
         [ -4. ],
         #...etc.
         [ 4. ],
         [ 4. ]])

arrC = ([[ -30. ],
         [ -30. ],
         #...etc.
         [ -30. ],
         [ -30. ]])

#color = ([ 0. , 10. , 20. , 30. , 40. , 50. , 60. , 50. , 40. , 30. , 20. , 10. , 0. ])

arrA = np.array(arrA)
arrB = np.array(arrB)
arrC = np.array(arrC)

data_arrays = (arrA, arrB, arrC)

X, Y, Z = data_arrays


#ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='inferno')


c = np.abs(color)
cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color, s=50, c=c, cmap=cmhot)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z');
plt.show()
```

/ .txt-file

```
0. , 10. , 20. , 30. , 40. , 50. , 60. , 50. , 40. , 30. , 20. , 10. , 0.
10. , 20. , 30. , 40. , 50. , 60. , 50. , 60. , 50. , 40. , 30. , 20. , 10.
20. , 30. , 40. , 50. , 60. , 50. , 40. , 50. , 60. , 50. , 40. , 30. , 10.
40. , 50. , 60. , 50. , 40. , 30. , 20. , 30. , 40. , 50. , 60. , 50. , 40.
60. , 50. , 40. , 30. , 20. , 10. , 0. , 10. , 20. , 30. , 40. , 50. , 60.
#... etc.
```

/ Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\te291095\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in to_rgba(c, alpha)
    165     try:
--> 166         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
    167     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.

KeyError: (nan, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-8ef706d1f4cb> in <module>()
     31 
     32 # parse good sensor data from imported data
---> 33 color = mpl.colors.to_rgba_array(data_file[:,0], alpha=None)
     34 #color = data_file[:,0]
     35 # display the first 16 sensor rows

c:\users\te291095\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in to_rgba_array(c, alpha)
    265     result = np.empty((len(c), 4), float)
    266     for i, cc in enumerate(c):
--> 267         result[i] = to_rgba(cc, alpha)
    268     return result
    269 

c:\users\te291095\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in to_rgba(c, alpha)
    166         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
    167     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.
--> 168         rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    169         try:
    170             _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha] = rgba

c:\users\te291095\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    217         # float)` and `np.array(...).astype(float)` all convert "0.5" to 0.5.
    218         # Test dimensionality to reject single floats.
--> 219         raise ValueError("Invalid RGBA argument: {!r}".format(orig_c))
    220     # Return a tuple to prevent the cached value from being modified.
    221     c = tuple(c.astype(float))

ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: nan
```

/ Verifyable:

The code shouold read the data from the file and process it as color for the points in the scatter-plot.

If you read three lines manually without the file and just save it as array it works (see picture below), so I don't understand why it won't work, when I get the data from the file.

[image: what it should display]

Comment: It's recommended to post in english. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Es tut mir Leid, dass der Code nicht sehr übersichtlich ist, aber ich habe halt schon viele mögliche Lösungen ausprobiert / I'm sorry that the code is not very clear, but I've already tried many possible solutions

Comment: Rather than apologizing for posting your complete code and just a vague description of what kind of idea of a visualization you'd like to get, I'd recommend you to please cut down the post to a short sample of the part of the code which fails. And as important as that please describe as concrete and exactly as possible what result you expect. I think nobody knows what you mean by some "interactive 3d-map", and sorry: no it is not obvious what you want. The main reason for this is that you probably thought about this for hours or days now and have a certain idea in your mind - but we didn't.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to use `to_rbga_array` or similar functions here. To me it looks as if you can just directly `ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, s=50, c=data_file[:,0], cmap="hot")`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to get you to a quick, complete working solution. In the exact same way as @Importance mentioned here above it would seem :).

Comment: Actually we know nothing about the length of `X`, `Y`  and `Z`. So I doubt it'll work out of the box. But it should give the right idea. Maybe it's rather `c=data_file.flatten()`, who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem you are reporting is with: `mpl.colors.to_rgba_array`
which expects an array of Matplotlib Color values, not floating point numbers.

Take a look here:
https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#module-matplotlib.colors

And also look at the following stack overflow post:
[How to map number to color using matplotlib's colormap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140072/how-to-map-number-to-color-using-matplotlibs-colormap#15140118)

you could fix it by changing it with something like the following (please take note of the arbitrary vmin and vmax values I chose):

```
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=60)
cmap = cm.hot
m = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
map_to_color = np.vectorize(m.to_rgba)

# parse good sensor data from imported data
color = map_to_color(data_file[:, 0])
```

There are further issues with the sample you've posted regarding the dimensionalities of what you pass to `ax.scatter` but I'm sure you can quickly fix that yourself.

**Edit:**

After looking at the matplotlib.pyplot.scatter some more (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), here is the quickest way to get your example working.

remove the faulty line:

```
color = mpl.colors.to_rgba_array(data_file[:,0], alpha=None)
```

and replace the block:

```
c = np.abs(color)
cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color, s=50, c=c, cmap=cmhot)
```

with:

```
values = data_file[:4, 0]
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=values, cmap="hot")
```

the `data_file[:4, 0]` instead of `data_file[:, 0]` is there to make sure the dimensionality of your input x and y (n=4) matches that of the colors/values passed to `c` (which should also be of lenght `n`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
I'll try and fix it as soon as possible and report back.

Comment: I tried to implement it into my code, but I still get the error, that it wont process the array.
_unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'_
Now there's a new error:
_c of shape (4, 16, 13) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 13, y with size 13_
I changed _color = map_to_color(data_file[:, 0])_ to _color = map_to_color(data_file[:, 0:13])_ Is this correct?
Could it be, that there's something wrong with np.abs()?

Comment: I've edited my answer to get you to a quick, complete working solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now.
Sorry to bother you again, but just a quick question...
Do you know where to search for a way to NOT make the scatter points in the background almost transparent?

Comment: just add `alpha=1` to the scatter call: `ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=values, alpha=1, cmap="hot")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@stakka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9267315/stakka) for the answer.
Now I shortend the code and deleted everything not necessary.
It now looks like this and works fine:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D, get_test_data
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

# set up a figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))

# add the projection
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

# load the data file
data_file = np.genfromtxt('data_file_noarr.txt', delimiter=',')

arrA = ([[0],[2],[4],[0],[2],[4],[0],[2],[4]])
arrB = ([[0],[0],[0],[2],[2],[2],[4],[4],[4]])

arrA = np.array(arrA)
arrB = np.array(arrB)

#          <-- Lowest Plot to Highest Plot loop -->
#################################################################

count = 0
cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")

while count < 10:
    values = data_file[0:9, count]
    arrC = np.full((9, 1), count)
    arrC = np.array(arrC)
    data_arrays = (arrA, arrB, arrC)
    X, Y, Z = data_arrays
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=values, cmap=cmhot)
    count = count + 1

#################################################################

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z');
plt.show()
```

/ Output:

[image: correct output]

Comment: to answer your question regarding the transparant points : you can avoid this by passing alpha=1 to the matplotlib.pyplot.scatter call.
I'd also like to mention that if you know the exact amount of required iterations, you should use a for loop instead of a while loop. Just write:
`for count in range(10):`

Comment: Yeah. Thanks.I wasn't used to the for syntax, so I just used while. But thanks for the fix with the transparency.