# Using matplotlib cmap function outside of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use the same mapping function as **matplotlib** **cmap** but outside of **matplotlib**. E.g.:

Given:

```py
plt.imshow(image, cmap="viridis")
```

Manually replicate same result such that every value of the `image[x,y]` → `RBG` triplet as per `viridis` color map.

Anyone knows the way to get to the function that does this?

Will be digging through the source in the mean time...

Thanks!

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140072/how-to-map-number-to-color-using-matplotlibs-colormap

Comment: For posterity what I actually looking for after going deep enough is this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/_cm.py